# Update view in Angular6 when we set variable in subscribe function

Tags: angular, angular4-router

First component which renders the file select html [image]

When I click on browse button I redirect to another component Fileselect component which is second component  `this.goto('fileselect');`

[image]

Problem is when I select a file from file component I have to display it in the input field of the first component

When I click on the Select class button I am calling redirect() function.

In file select component I have used service to pass the file name to the first component as shown in the below code

```
 redirect(){
  this._messageService.filter(this.selectedFile);
  this.router.navigateByUrl('');
```

}

And in the First Component where I want this file name, I have subscribed to function as shown

```
ngOnInit() {
   this._messageService.listen().subscribe((m:any) => {
            this.fileName = m
            this.loadXMLasJSON()
            console.log(this.fileName)

});}
```

I am assigning the variable that is this.fileName in the subscribe function when I console.log I am getting the filename. But the view is not getting updated.

My view code

```
 <input type="text"  class="form-control image-preview-filename" value="{{fileName}}" />
```

What could be the problem?

Please help me with this.

Comment: What is the value of `this.fileName`?

Comment: It is the file name that i have selected like example.xml

Comment: I would suggest prefer ngModel and second to update the view, inject Changedetectorref in your constructor and in your subscribe method use markForCheck() or detectChanges() methods from Changedetectorref. Call one of these methods after assigning  the value of filename

Comment: @SumeetKale when i do that i get error ViewDestroyedError: Attempt to use a destroyed view: detectChanges

Comment: Got it. Your navigation method is wrong I guess. Are you using normal router outlet or named router outlet. I think you can solve this using named router outlet. In which you can navigate the fileselect route in a named router outlet which should prevent your first component to not get destroyed on navigation

Comment: @SumeetKale let me try that approach, thanks

Answer (score 0):

Use `[ngModel]` instead of `value`:

```
<input type="text"  class="form-control image-preview-filename" [ngModel]="fileName" />
```

Answer (score -2):

Kindly remove **double quotes** from **value** attribute.

**Change** it to:

`<input type="file"  class="form-control image-preview-filename" value={{fileName}} />`

Comment: Done, it did not make any difference

Comment: Try [(ngModel)] then

Comment: Change the input type to file from text.
Hope it'll work. :)